# RuntimeBinderException with RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm getting this when I try to initialize a RavenDB embedded database:

> "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Raven.Abstractions.Linq.DynamicJsonObject' does not contain a definition for '__document_id'

Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 1):

You are pausing on all exceptions, hit F5 and it will continue normally.
This is how dynamic types works in C#